# Laravel route() redirect to http://localhostarticle

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

Why may Laravel route() redirect to http://localhostarticle instead http://localhost/article

**blog.conf**

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/blog/public
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/blog/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/blog/access.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/blog/public">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Send requests to public directory...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using the default `.htaccess` - https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess. I'm not an expert with `.htaccess` but you have set up your virtualhost to go straight to the public directory, but you are using a rule in your `.htaccess` to send requests to public... Try replacing your `.htaccess` with the default one and see if that helps.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you running, @aisthetes?

Comment: Laravel 5.2. Thats not help...

Comment: can you share your routes(in question) and, which routes redirects you to the invalid path ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all redirects from apache vhost and its helped